# Programmatically set the permissions on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-grant

I want to programmatically set the permissions (i.e. GRANT) on a newly created table. I was hoping to get SQL Server to show me the script for that by going to another table in the database and doing a right-click and then "Script Table as" but I don't see the option for GRANT underneath that.

Is it possible to get SQL Server to show me the script for this?

Comment: like `grant select on SomeTable to SomeUser`? Or just `GRANT ALL` which on a table would be `DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE`

Comment: A specific user, with specific privileges.

Comment: The *real* problem is not setting permissions--it's *fetching existing permissions* on a particular table. Is that right?

Comment: I want to programmatically set permissions on a new table. I can use an existing table that has the same permissions I want for the new table as a model. Suppose I wanted to create a table exactly like an existing one. I can right-click on the table and select _Script Table as -> Create To_ and code will appear that can create that table exactly. I want to do that, but with permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look around some more. The simple version is to use the dialog where you set permissions. E.g.,

[image]

A more general and advanced approach - with far more options - is to use the script feature at the database level. On your database, rt click and select , , and then run through the wizard to select your table and the scripting options you want. Be sure to click the Advanced button in the scripting options tab - where you will see "object-level permissions" (off by default).

Comment: Thanks this looks like the right place. However, when I pull down on _Script_ and select _Script Action to New Query Window_, I get the message "There is no action to be scripted". This happens for any of the selections under _Script_. I have the Permissions page selected on the left and also the row in the *Users or roles:* list selected and there are Permissions selected (in this case Grant:Delete, Grant:Insert, Grant:Select and Grant:Update.

Comment: Then you did not change anything. The first suggestion applies when you are making permission changes and want to see the actual tsql script that will be executed for the changes made **at that particular point in time**.

Comment: OIC, that's cool, I can just uncheck those boxes and then check them again to see the script.

Answer (score 1):

Too long to comment.

```
GRANT <n> ON YourDatabase.YourSchema.YourTable TO YourSpecificUser
```

In this case, since it's a table `<n>` can be one of the following:

- `DELETE`
- `INSERT`
- `REFERENCES`
- `SELECT`
- `UPDATE`

Note, if a user has a [fixed database role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles), they could have more access than you explicitly grant them. Read more about [GRANT Object Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql).

Of note, to return a list of permissions on a table, you can use [sp_table_privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-table-privileges-transact-sql)

```
sp_table_privileges @table_name = 'YourTable'
```

You can capture these results and then loop through them to build a dynamic sql query.

Replace the script below with your `TableName` and what ever your `NewTableName` is. When you are satisfied with the print out, you can uncomment the `exec(@sql)` to execute the code that's printed.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#priv') is not null
drop table #priv

create table #priv( ID int identity (1,1)
                    ,TABLE_QUALIFIER varchar(64)
                    ,TABLE_OWNER VARCHAR(64)
                    ,TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(64)
                    ,GRANTOR VARCHAR(64)
                    ,GRANTEE VARCHAR(64)
                    ,PRIVILEGE VARCHAR(64)
                    ,IS_GRANTABLE VARCHAR(8))

insert into #priv
exec sp_table_privileges @table_name = 'YourTableName'

declare @i int = 1
declare @max int = (select max(id) from #priv)
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

while (@i <= @max)
begin
    set @sql = @sql + (select ' GRANT ' + stuff(PRIVILEGE,1,0,' ') + ' ON ' + stuff(TABLE_NAME,1,0,' ') + ' TO ' + stuff(GRANTEE,1,0,' ') + char(13) + ' GO ' + char(13) from #priv where ID = @i)
    set @i = @i + 1
end

print(@sql)
set @sql = replace(@sql,'YourTableName','NewTableName')
print(@sql)
--exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: So you want to use the results of the procedure along with a cursor and dynamic sql it seems